# Solana web3 js keep gives Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tostring') while trying to confirm transaction

Tags: spl-token

Here is my code

```
    const senderAassociatedToken = await Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      mint,
      senderKey,
    );

    const receiverAassociatedToken = await Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      mint,
      receiverKey,
    );

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      Token.createTransferInstruction(
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        senderAassociatedToken,
        receiverAassociatedToken,
        senderKey,
        [],
        1,
      ),
    );

 

    transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

    let blockhashObj = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();

    transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockhashObj.blockhash;

    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
      wallet.publicKey,
    ]);
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: May want to show the whole file too so folks can replicate

Answer (score 4):

The method signature of `signAndSendTransaction` is:

```
function sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection: Connection,
  transaction: Transaction,
  signers: Array<Signer>,
  options?: ConfirmOptions,
): Promise<TransactionSignature>;
```

The third parameter must be an array of `Signer` objects.

A `Signer` is defined as:

```
interface Signer {
  publicKey: PublicKey;
  secretKey: Uint8Array;
}
```

In your example, you've supplied a single public key (`wallet.publicKey`) as the argument. The code is trying to call `.{publicKey|secretKey}.toString()` on that, which is equivalent to calling `toString()` on `undefined`.

Change `[wallet.publicKey]` to `[wallet]`.

Comment: The real question is: why didn't your Typescript compiler let you know that you had the wrong argument type for `Array<Signer>`. Do you have Typescript enabled in your editor?